# Why does ''GLOBIGNORE=keepfile rm *'' delete keepfile?

Tags: bash

There is something I am not really getting:

```
touch a b c ; mkdir -p git ; mkdir -p iii/ooo/ppp ; touch git/rtdsfgsdg  ; touch .sdfsadf
```

So, did that produce what I wanted?

```
» tree -a
.
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── git
│   └── rtdsfgsdg
├── iii
│   └── ooo
│       └── ppp
└── .sdfsadf

4 directories, 5 files
```

Yepp. Some files, one dir, one hidden file. All good.

Now I want to delete everything, but I want to keep the hidden file and the `git` directory. `GLOBIGNORE` to the rescue!

```
GLOBIGNORE=git rm -rf *
```

How did it went?

```
» tree -a
.
└── .sdfsadf

0 directories, 1 file
```

Simply awful. Where is my `git` folder? Why is `GLOBIGNORE` not working as advertised?

```
   GLOBIGNORE
          A  colon-separated  list  of  patterns  defining the set of file
          names to be ignored by  pathname  expansion.   If  a  file  name
          matched  by a pathname expansion pattern also matches one of the
          patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.
```

I am on:

```
» bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: (We do have existing Q&A entries providing essentially the same answer to the closely related question "why does `var=old; var=new echo "$var"` print `old` instead of `new`?"; but they're not easy to find search-keyword-wise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you're using to temporarily apply the variable *only applies at execution time, not at parse time*; consequently, it can't change how the glob is expanded, because replacing the `*` with a list of files happens before `rm` is invoked.

To modify parse-time behavior, split into two separate commands:

```
GLOBIGNORE=git
rm -rf *
```

See this running successfully at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/LovablePoliticalPrograms

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's obvious. Thanks!